# Saving content of large structure

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I have a really big data structure with a lot of fields in it.

I want to save its fields to later compare with later values; but I can't print the content to console, because it's too much code to write by hand.  (I have roughly 1k fields.)

How should I solve my problem?

Comment: What language?  Why do you have **1,000 fields** instead of some array or container?  Real programmers don't eat quiche, but they do generate their own code instead of writing it by hand.

Comment: It located in .net environment.

Comment: I am talking about stracture that contains a lot of strictures of different types in it.
And i need to compare their all fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use serialization: some tutorial [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-serialize-objects-to-a-file) or [here](http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=94).

Answer (score 0):

write the stricture to a file and use some good diff tools.

Comment: How i can write it to file ? I don't have any overloaded output operator for it .

Comment: @Night you need to write the output code yourself then. I mean you printout each field of that structure.

Comment: As wrote i have there about 1k different fields .